# XAML: How to bind over 2 properties to a DynamicResourceExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `ResourceDictionary` for Colors:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Color x:Key="Ori">#000000</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then use `DynamicResource` to reference them:

```
<DynamicResource x:Key="Ref", ResourceKey="Ori" />
```

When over 2 properties bind to `Ref`:

```
<SomeControl1.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Ref}">
</SomeControl1.Background>

<SomeControl2.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Ref}">
</SomeControl2.Background>
```

It would cause when running:

> "Ref" is not a valid value for property "Color"

I guess that's because they're both `TwoWay` Bindings.
Any method to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it in that way:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Color x:Key="Ori">#000000</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Your controls:

```
<SomeControl1.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Ori}">
</SomeControl1.Background>

<SomeControl2.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Ori}">
</SomeControl2.Background>
```

Using also `StaticResource` is weird.